# PDO insertion sqlerv format mismatch on CLOB

Tags: sql, sql-server, pdo, clob, sqlsrv

On a MsSQL server when I run

```
UPDATE post SET description='Hodor, hodor; hodor hodor... Hodor hodor hodor hodor! Hodor! Hodor hodor, hodor hodor HODOR hodor, 
                             hodor hodor, hodor. Hodor hodor. Hodor. Hodor. Hodor hodor hodor hodor. Hodor, hodor - hodor, 
                             hodor. Hodor hodor?  Hodor hodor - hodor hodor hodor hodor hodor. Hodor. Hodor HODOR hodor, 
                             hodor hodor - hodor. Hodor, hodor; hodor hodor hodor?! Hodor hodor, hodor. Hodor hodor; hodor hodor. 
                             Hodor hodor - hodor hodor hodor - hodor, hodor. Hodor hodor. Hodor. Hodor hodor - hodor hodor hodor hodor hodor; 
                             hodor hodor. Hodor hodor; hodor hodor hodor hodor?! lol' 
WHERE post.id=4
```

with PDO and after run

```
SELECT CAST(description AS VARCHAR(1000)) AS description from post where id = 4 ;`
```

it returns:

`Hodor, hodor; hodor hodor... Hodor hodor hodor hodor! Hodor! Hodor hodor, hodor hodor HODOR hodor, hodor hodor, hodor. Hodor hodor. Hodor. Hodor. Hodor hodor hodor hodor. Hodor, hodor - hodor, hodor. Hodor hodor? Hodor hodor - hodor hodor hodor hodor hodor. Hodor. Hodor HODOR hodor, hodor hodor - hodor. Hodor, hodor; hodor hodor hodor?! Hodor hodor, hodor. Hodor hodor; hodor hodor. Hodor hodor - hodor hodor hodor - hodor, hodor. Hodor hodor. Hodor. Hodor hodor - hodor hodor hodor hodor hodor; hodor hodor. Hodor hodor; hodor hodor hodor hodor?! lol?????�???����???????�???�?�?�???�?�?????�?�O�???�?�?????��?????�?�Š�???�?�?????�?�?????�??????�??���� �����?????�????��?????????��?????????�???��?????????�???��?????????�???��?????????�???��?????????�???��?????????�???��?????????�???��????`

If I run the same update request with dbVisualizer, it inserts the correct value.

the description column is a CLOB object.

Comment: Can you try by converting column datatype to text rather than clob.

Comment: same things with text type

Answer (score 0):

I tried as follows:(works properly in my case):

```
create table test_table (id int, descs text)

insert into test_table values ('4','hodor; hodor hodor... Hodor hodor hodor hodor! Hodor! Hodor hodor, hodor hodor HODOR hodor, 
                             hodor hodor, hodor. Hodor hodor. Hodor. Hodor. Hodor hodor hodor hodor. Hodor, hodor - hodor, 
                             hodor. Hodor hodor?  Hodor hodor - hodor hodor hodor hodor hodor. Hodor. Hodor HODOR hodor, 
                             hodor hodor - hodor. Hodor, hodor; hodor hodor hodor?! Hodor hodor, hodor. Hodor hodor; hodor hodor. 
                             Hodor hodor - hodor hodor hodor - hodor, hodor. Hodor hodor. Hodor. Hodor hodor - hodor hodor hodor hodor hodor; 
                             hodor hodor. Hodor hodor; hodor hodor hodor hodor?! lol') 


select * from test_table
```

Output:

```
id    descs
4     hodor; hodor hodor... Hodor hodor hodor hodor! Hodor! Hodor hodor, hodor hodor HODOR hodor, 
                             hodor hodor, hodor. Hodor hodor. Hodor. Hodor. Hodor hodor hodor hodor. Hodor, hodor - hodor, 
                             hodor. Hodor hodor?  Hodor hodor - hodor hodor hodor hodor hodor. Hodor. Hodor HODOR hodor, 
                             hodor hodor - hodor. Hodor, hodor; hodor hodor hodor?! Hodor hodor, hodor. Hodor hodor; hodor hodor. 
                             Hodor hodor - hodor hodor hodor - hodor, hodor. Hodor hodor. Hodor. Hodor hodor - hodor hodor hodor hodor hodor; 
                             hodor hodor. Hodor hodor; hodor hodor hodor hodor?! lol
```

Comment: do you try with propel ?